# Leaflet map locationfound triggers unintended listener

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map in which `map.locate()` can be called in two ways: 1. Easybutton location button, 2. A regular call every minute using setTimeout.

Each has their own `locationfound` listener, or at least I would like them to have - this is the problem: clicking the easybutton triggers both the `control._map.on('locationfound'..)` easybutton listener, AND the `map.on('locationfound'..)` listener inside getLocation().

The regular call to getLocation() only triggers the `map.on('locationfound'..)` listener.
Is this something to do with scope?
How do I get it so the easybutton only triggers its intended listener and the setTimeout call to map.locate() only triggers the listener in getLocation()?

```
  L.easyButton({
    position: easy_position,
    states:[
      {
        stateName: 'unloaded',
        icon: 'fa-location-arrow',
        title: 'load image',
        onClick: function(control){
          control.state("loading");
          control._map.on('locationfound', function(e){
            alert('location found - easybutton');
            this.setView(e.latlng,18); // go to current location
            control.state('loaded');
            setTimeout(function(){
              control.state('unloaded');
            }, 3000);
          });
          control._map.on('locationerror', function(){
            control.state('error');
            setTimeout(function(){
              control.state('unloaded');
            }, 3000);
          });
          control._map.locate();
          setTimeout(function(){
            control.state('unloaded');
          }, 10000);  // give it ten seconds to find the location
        }
      }, {
        stateName: 'loading',
        icon: 'fa-spinner fa-spin'
      }, {
        stateName: 'loaded',
        icon: 'fa-thumbs-up'
      }, {
        stateName: 'error',
        icon: 'fa-frown-o',
        title: 'location not found'
      }
    ]
  }).addTo(map);
```

```
  function updateLocation() {
    getLocation(false);
    setTimeout(updateLocation, 60000);
  }

  getLocation = function(goToLocation) {
    map.on('locationfound', function(e) {
      alert('location found - getLocation()');
      var lat = e.latitude;
      var lng = e.longitude;
      if(goToLocation) {
        pan_to(lat,lng,0.5);
      }
    });
    map.on('locationerror', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
    map.locate({
      setView: false,
      maxZoom: 16
    });
  }
```

Comment: Consider using the browser's geolocation API directly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/Using_the_Geolocation_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mitigate your issue by using [`map.once()` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#evented-once) to attach your event listeners (both in your regular process and in your button), so that they are removed after firing once:

> Behaves as `on(…)`, except the listener will only get fired once and then removed.

There are still some transient situations where both listeners can be fired at the same time: in case your button is clicked while your regular process has initiated a location, but the result is still pending, or the reverse.

Unfortunately Leaflet does not differentiate between calls to `map.locate()` method. Hence @IvanSanchez's suggestion of directly using the browser API.

You could eliminate those transient situations by managing a flag / mutex whenever you start a location, and not execute the other, or delay it, in case your mutex is locked.

Comment: Both the map.once() and the flag approaches seem perfectly satisfactory. I was wondering if there may be a more elegant solution invoving scopes. Regarding the browser's API solution - I don't see how that changes the fundamental problem? What can you do with the browser API that you can't with leaflet?

Comment: A more creative solution, that you could say is closer to using scopes, could be to use a dummy map just for a different location.

Comment: With the browser API, you specify the action directly as a callback, hence you could also say it uses scopes. Whereas with Leaflet you have to go through events, but there is no information about different sources.